# Showing a topology on a Set

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove that $\tau=\lbrace G\subset [0,1]: GG\subset G\rbrace$ is a topology on $[0,1]$, where $GG=\lbrace xy: x,y\in G \rbrace$.

Comment: and what have you tried? some properties are obvious, so which one are you stuck on?

Comment: Obviously $\emptyset$ and $[0,1]$ are members. The problem is that I feel that the members belong to this class $\tau$ must be of the form $(0,a)$ , $(0,a]$, $[0,a]$ or $[0,a)$ along with $\lbrace 0\rbrace, \lbrace 1 \rbrace, \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. But how to write all this things?

Comment: Before you worry about exactly what the members of $\tau$ look like, can you prove that $G\cap H\in\tau$ whenever $G,H\in\tau$? If you can, then you know that everything hinges on whether $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary unions, and you can focus your efforts a little more narrowly.

Comment: Yes, I proved that $G\cap H\in \tau$ whenever $G,H\in \tau$.

Comment: Then you’ve done the groundwork and are ready for the hint that I just left. (This is a cute problem; I’ve not seen it before.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $a\in[0,1]$, then $\{a^n:n\in\Bbb N\}\in\tau$. Is $\tau$ closed under unions?

Comment: Definitely not...$\lbrace2^{-n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \rbrace, \lbrace 3^{-n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\rbrace$ are in $\tau$ but not their union, right?

Comment: @sucharita: Yep. That’s exactly the example that I was thinking of, in fact.

Comment: So a should not be in $[0,1]$ always, isn't it?

Comment: @Sucharita: No, what that shows is that $\tau$ isn’t a topology, because it fails to closed under taking unions. Every one of those sets $\{a^{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ (with $a\in[0,1]$ **is** in $\tau$, and that’s the problem.

Comment: @ Brian: But if you choose $a\in [0,1]$, say $0.5$, then the set $\lbrace a^{-n}:n\in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ won't be a subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Sucharita: Oops! Sorry: that should of course be $\{a^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. I’ll fix that in the hint in just a moment. *pause* Fixed now.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Yes, I got it, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sucharita: You’re welcome.